# Mongoose increase performance on writes

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a nodejs app using mongoose to model my data.  For 95% of my data (not high write volume) mongoose works great.

I do however have one collection that has a very high write volume.  Doing some benchmarking and I am wondering if there is a way to increase performance for this collection.

I have tried using the native driver to insert

```
Model.collection.insert(doc, {w: 0});
```

And I don't see much of an increase.

What does this mean.  Well it could mean mongoose is running very fast and bypassing it gave no performance boost.  I.E. it might be mongodb (connection pool, setup, etc) that might need to be tuned.

My performance is not an issue as of yet, but for this collection I do not need any kind of verification on insert.  I would like to just throw the data at mongo and I do not care if there is an error.  Any way to do this through mongoose?

Comment: Their are multiple ways to increase write performance. One of them is to reduce the amount of indexes you have. It is possible to make bulk inserts if applicable to you case. If writes performance is still a problem, you could buffer/cache your writes into Redis for faster read/write. But to be honest, you will need a f* load of traffic to actually need that.

Comment: Using Redis is a good idea, if I ever need it :) Thanks for the tip!